# Run foreach with 2 different background styles

Tags: laravel, foreach

[image: The layout im using for the foreach loop to return data to]I am trying to run a foreach loop to return the title and price. But i need the results to go into different boxes, one has a background img, the other has no background img. The boxes alternate down the page.

[image: Bootstrap row and columns, one with bg image, the other without[![][1]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crseC.jpg)

Comment: so what's the problem? can you elaborate more your question?

Comment: I know how to run a foreach loop, but not for 2 differently styled boxes

Comment: write code and I convert it to forech not use image

Comment: create a `boolean` outside the `foreach`, then inside the `foreach` loop load the content conditionally checking that `boolean` and just set it to the inverse at the end with `$boolean = !$boolean`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you're referring to dynamic adding a class `card-w-bg` to your cards.

Solution 1: Adding `background` boolean to your card and use it to determine.

```
@foreach($cards as $card)
<div class="col-4">
    <div class="card x-auto @if($card->background) card-w-bg @endif">
        {{ $card->title }}
        {{ $card->description }}
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Solution 2: In your case, it seems like the background appears at the odd number of your cards.  Use [the loop variable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#the-loop-variable).

```
<div class="@if($loop->odd) card-w-bg @endif">
```

However, the `$loop->even` only works in Laravel 5.8. Use `@if($loop->iteration % 2)` instead if below Laravel 5.8

Comment: This is a really nice approach. Wasn't aware of the `$loop` variable.

Comment: Thanks Cloud Soh...I used <div class="@if($loop->odd) card-w-bg @endif">, works perfectly, cheers

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? http://image.intervention.io/api/text

Hint: you can capture the image size and do the math to set the text X,Y for the text overlay.